# convert comparator to lambda in Kotlin

Tags: lambda, kotlin

There is a code snipt in my Kotlin code:

```
val dataMap = sensoryDataUsage.groupBy { it }
        .mapValues { it.value.count().toDouble()/count }
        .mapKeys { println(it.key); it.key.toDouble()/max }
        .toSortedMap(object : Comparator<Double> {
            override fun compare(p0: Double, p1: Double): Int {
                return (p1-p0).compareTo(0)
            }
        })
```

It worked just fine. However the IDE keeps suggesting me to convert that Comparator object to a lambda, and I did just that:

```
val dataMap = sensoryDataUsage.groupBy { it }
        .mapValues { it.value.count().toDouble()/count }
        .mapKeys { println(it.key); it.key.toDouble()/max }
        .toSortedMap {x, y -> (y-x).compareTo(0)}
```

This shold work. However, it can't be compiled:

```
Error:(32, 14) Kotlin: Type inference failed: fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.toSortedMap(comparator: Comparator<in K>): SortedMap<K, V> cannot be applied to receiver: Map<Double, Double>  arguments: ((Double, Double) -> Int)
```

Any ideas what went wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you convert it manually or apply an intention provided by the IDE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this way:

```
val dataMap = sensoryDataUsage.groupBy { it }
        .mapValues { it.value.count().toDouble()/count }
        .mapKeys { println(it.key); it.key.toDouble()/max }
        .toSortedMap(Comparator<Double> { p0, p1 -> (p1-p0).compareTo(0) })
```

You have a lot of answers with working code, but I'll try to explain why didn't your code work. Take a look on this lambda:

```
p0, p1 -> (p1-p0).compareTo(0)
```

It would generate a method which one returns type specified inside of the last called method, in our case - `compareTo`. In another words - this lambda would return integer. But your code needs a double, so you should specify type of returning value as `Double`. Now when you got a reasons feel free to use any of suggested solutions, which fits you better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand. You said "this lambda would return integer. But your code needs a double" however the Comparator's compareTo method needs to return an int, not a Double. More to the point, if I replace the lambda with "p0, p1 -> 0.0" it still doesn't work despite returning a Double. As far as I can tell it's because the compiler can't infer the types of p0 and p1, but I don't know why (interestingly, it can infer the types in the case of Collections.sort(...)).

Comment: @TheIT, actually you are right, it can't inherit type and I also can't say why it could be inherited from `Collections.sort` and could not be done here. Hmm, sorry, I thought compareTo returns a value with a type of input. Let me know about your investigation, maybe we can improve and complete this answer

Answer (score 3):

your code should be like this:

```
val dataMap = sensoryDataUsage.groupBy { it }
    .mapValues { it.value.count().toDouble()/count }
    .mapKeys { println(it.key); it.key.toDouble()/max }
    .toSortedMap(Comparator<Double>{x, y -> (y-x).compareTo(0)});
```

**OR** you can remove the `y-x` expression:

```
val dataMap = sensoryDataUsage.groupBy { it }
    .mapValues { it.value.count().toDouble()/count }
    .mapKeys { println(it.key); it.key.toDouble()/max }
    .toSortedMap(Comparator<Double>{x, y -> y.compareTo(x)});
```

**OR** using `compareByDescending` instead:

```
val dataMap = sensoryDataUsage.groupBy { it }
    .mapValues { it.value.count().toDouble()/count }
    .mapKeys { println(it.key); it.key.toDouble()/max }
    .toSortedMap(compareByDescending{ it });
```

Comment: or you can use Comparator<Double> to specify type of lambda's return

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
.toSortedMap {x, y -> (y-x).compareTo(0)}
```

with

```
.toSortedMap {x:Double, y:Double -> (y-x).compareTo(0)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{x, y -> y.compareTo(x)}
```